# Практическое применение клики?

Tags: сеть, графы, c++, нейронные-сети, моделирование

В теории графов кликой неориентированного графа называется подмножество его вершин, таких, что любые две вершины подмножества соединены ребром. То есть клика это подмножество вершин графа, которое само по себе образует полный граф. как бы маленький полный граф внутри большого графа.

Есть ли практический смысл задачи поиска клики? Бывает ли для чего-то нужно в большой компьютерной сети, иной сети, или вообще у чего-либо, что можно представить в виде графа необходимость искать эту самую клику?

Comment: например, есть граф сети. И если в этом графе есть клика, значит, есть такие пары узлов, которые могут быть связаны разными путями. В некоторых случаях это зацикливание стараются избегать.

Comment: Детектирование дорвеев поисковиком, чтобы исключить их из результатов поиска?

Answer (score 2):

Например, поиск в соц. сетях максимальной группы пользователей, все члены которой связаны отношениями дружбы между собой, а так же для [моделирования в биоинформатике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Клика_%28теория_графов%29#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), анализа коммуникационных сетей и т.д.